# expanded menu doesn't appears over flash image

Tags: css, flash, drop-down-menu, swfobject

I have a drop-down/multi-level CSS menu on a page. The menu however doesn't appear over a  flash.i put `<param value="transparent" name="wmode"/>`

I added `wmode="transparent"` to the EMBED tag then the expanded menu appeared but the color of flash image diaappeared also tried z-index in css.

```
<div id="swfhead">
    <object height="205" width="950">
        <param value="images/pesbanner.swf" name="movie">
        <embed height="205" width="950" src="images/pesbanner.swf">
    </object>
</div>
```

in style.css

```
#primary-menu ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 500;
}
#swfhead {
z-index:0;
}
```

this menu content is hiding behind the flash.

Comment: <div id="swfhead" style="position:relative;z-index:0;"> as far as I know both elements needs to have position set. only this way div swhead will now that it should go under the primary-menu. But still, I might be wrong.

Comment: now expanded menu appeared..but color of the flash image disappeared

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your prams by adding this :

wmode="transparent"

```
<param value="images/pesbanner.swf" name="movie" wmode="transparent">
```

Comment: i tried like this..but expanded menu doesn't appears.it is hiding behind flash

Comment: add position:relative to #swfhead. Sorry, missed that.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
To preserve your flash background, put it in div style, such as

```
<div style="z-index:0; background:#ff0000">
```

---

Wrap your flash content in a div and apply "z-index" to "0"

Add `< param name="wmode" value="transparent" />` to your object tag

Set wmode="transparent" in the embed tag.

This is a working example:

```
<div id="flashContent" style="z-index:0;">

<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="100%" height="100%" id="00" align="middle">

<param name="movie" value="your_flash.swf" />

<param name="quality" value="high" />

<param name="bgcolor" value="#9d9d9d" />

<param name="play" value="true" />

<param name="loop" value="true" />

<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />

<param name="scale" value="showall" />

<param name="menu" value="true" />

<param name="devicefont" value="false" />

<param name="salign" value="lt" />

<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />

<!--[if !IE]>-->

<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="your_flash.swf" width="100%" height="100%">

<param name="movie" value="your_flash.swf" />

<param name="quality" value="high" />

<param name="bgcolor" value="#9d9d9d" />

<param name="play" value="true" />

<param name="loop" value="true" />

<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />

<param name="scale" value="showall" />

<param name="menu" value="true" />

<param name="devicefont" value="false" />

<param name="salign" value="lt" />

<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />

<!--<![endif]-->

<a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash">

<img src="flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" />

</a>

<!--[if !IE]>-->

</object>

<!--<![endif]-->

</object>

</div>
```

Comment: i put wmode="transparent" in the embed tag then expanded menu appeared..but the color of the flash image disappeared

Comment: put your desired background in the div, not in flash.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the wmode to both the object *and* embed.

```
<object height="205" width="950">
        <param value="images/pesbanner.swf" name="movie">
        <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
        <embed height="205" width="950" src="images/pesbanner.swf" wmode="transparent">
</object>
```

This should now work as you expect.

---

Ahh, all you need to do to get the Flash bg back is:

```
z-index:0; 
background:#ff0000
```

On the parent element.

Comment: If this is the answer that provided the solution, please mark it as accepted by clicking the tick next to it. An upvote would be great too ;)

Comment: @Kyle, why are you posting duplicated answers?... i've already written the same before on my answer.

Comment: _Tick_ can be a thing that gets under your skin.. where as _Checkmark_ never gets under your skin.

Comment: Hehe, you're definitely right there! I'd checkmark your comment, were it possible.

Comment: @Michele Virgilio: I am not duplicating answers, just working off the comments I got. Sorry if yours was the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try < param name="wmode" value="opaque" />